# Dropdown react fiber make it impossible to click on option tag from devtool console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, automation, react-three-fiber, chromedp

I'am working on an automation project with chromedp, I'am having trouble with the automation of a dropdown button.

Im using the chrome devtool to test my selectors, and other JS that I evaluate then in my chromedp code. Here is the dropdown element I'm talking about.

[dropdown with option childrens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USw3z.png)

First I notice that the click function on the select element is not working, after playing around a little I figure out that the "showPicker" function act as a click on this element so I crafted this instruction :
`var el = document.querySelector('[data-testid="datepicker-year"]'); el.showPicker(); var opt = el.querySelector('[value="1994"]'); opt.addEventListener("click", function () {console.log("clicked")}); opt.click()`

Here is a gif of the execution :
[execution gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4CMO.gif)

If someone have some clue I could work with it would be much appreciated.

EDIT : To reply to @James no the element doesn't respond to a change trigger.It does not seem to have any change listener attached to it. So here is the monitored click event that occur when clicking a year from the datepicker select button.

[click event part 1]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zze22.png)

[click event part 2]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZh2i.png)

[click event part 3]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v1jR.png)

[click event part 4]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhCfa.png)

[click event part 5]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSNB1.png)

Thank you !

Comment: I don’t understand what problem you are having.  You run the code and it says clicked twice. Is that the problem?  Why?

Comment: Look at the code,  it should be clicking on the year 1994. The console trigger like the <option value="1994"/> have been clicked but it is not (the ui dont change at all, and if I click on the submit button i have the error that the year is wrong

Comment: I guess that your datepicker is listening to "change" event on the select - this doesn't fire when you trigger a click on an option.

Comment: Try `el.value = '1994'; el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`

Comment: sorry for tha late reply i was trying your guess, but unfortunately it is not working.
I tried to log the event and replicate the action manualy i will update the code to post the screenshots, what do you think of the click event (cf post) ? it seem odd to me, bc I dont see any chance event listener on the element.

Comment: You might need to trigger "input" event instead of "change" (again this is on the select not the option).